# How can I get data with key

Tags: node.js, database, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I want to find data with `key` from google datastore

in normal RDB

```
select * from items where key = '123124124234221'
```

in GQL Query

```
SELECT * from items WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR KEY(item, 123124124234221)
```

it works!

but in nodejs

```
let query = datastoreClient.createQuery('items')
  .hasAncestor(datastoreClient.key(['item', '123124124234221']))

datastoreClient.runQuery(query, (err, entity) => {
  if (err) { reject(err) }
  console.log(entity)
})
```

result is empty []

please help how to get a data with key in node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than doing a query, you should do a direct get on the entity.

```
var key = datastoreClient.key(['item', datastore.int('123124124234221')]);
datastoreClient.get(key, function(err, entity) {
  console.log(err || entity);
});
```

Comment: Saved me a bunch of time!

Answer (score 0):

i answer my self

need `datastoreClient.int(_id)`

```
let query = datastoreClient.createQuery(keyName)
  .hasAncestor(datastoreClient.key([keyName, datastoreClient.int(_id)]))
```